# Can't run docker commands

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

After I installed docker, restarted my machine, I keep getting this error whenever I try to run any docker command:

```
FATA[0000] Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/containers/create: read unix /var/run/docker.sock: connection reset by peer. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

It happens even with: `docker version`

I can't understand it, I've already added my user to `docker` group

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker kristian
```

Nothing yet, keep throwing that same error.

I'm on Linux mint Rafaela, it is based on Ubuntu trusty tahr

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I know this is because the daemon is not running, but it happens even if I run it:

```
sudo service docker start
```

Seems to start, but then the same error, I just can't run any docker command.

Comment: Make sure to install xcode in you machine. I think it have some dependencies on that.

Comment: Hi, but this is basically Ubuntu, You mean xcode mac IDE?

Comment: I was assuming you are dong in mac machine. I never tried in Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you try to add this variable to your docker daemon config: `DOCKER_OPTS="-D --tls=false"` , then restart docker daemon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your docker daemon is not starting. Check `/var/log/upstart/docker.log` for the reasons why.

You are also on an old version of Docker too, normally the quickest way to get Docker back up and running is to update and reset it, which will fix any config and file system problems.

Note that a "reset" will remove all Docker data, so if you have any containers you need to keep, don't do this. You might need to further investigate errors if the update doesn't fix the problem.

#### 1. Upgrade docker

Use the Docker built packages to get the current version of docker installed.

Ubuntu install instructions are available on the Docker site: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/

It looks like some Mint versions might need the `apparmor` and or `cgroup-lite` packages to be installed as well.

#### 2. Reset Docker

**WARNING** This will remove *ALL* docker data and start afresh. Do not do this if you have data/container/images/config you need or back it up before removing it all.

```
rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

#### 3. Start Docker

```
sudo service docker start
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank You very much!